# CSS ::before is nullifying ::first-letter

Tags: html, css

Html code:

```
<h1>Example title</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1::first-letter{
    display:none;
}
h1::before{
    content: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ariil/alphabet/32/Letter-E-icon.png);
}
```

My question is: Why is ::before is killing ::first-letter rule? What is going on here? If ::before is removed, ::first-letter works fine.

Is there any alternative to target the first-letter in this example without changing html?

http://jsfiddle.net/Borachio/kvaxmhth/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#application-in-css):

> After the rule `p::before {content: "Note: "}`, the selector
>   `p::first-letter matches the "N" of "Note"`.

Note also that the `display` property is invalid on `:first-letter` and `:first-line` pseudo elements. Again, from the spec:

> A future version of this specification may allow this pseudo-element
>   to apply to more display types.

This is the intended behavior.

## Workaround:

HTML:

```
<div><h1>Example title</h1></div>
```

and CSS:

```
h1{
    display: inline-block;
}
h1::first-letter{
    font-size: 0px;
}
div::before{
    content: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ariil/alphabet/32/Letter-E-icon.png);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kvaxmhth/3/

Comment: So, Why the image is being displayed? The display:none shouldn't be applied to the image in this logic?

Comment: The image is an image, not a letter.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't killing, the **::first-letter** doesn't have the **display** declaration.

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

Comment: Seems to work with Visibility: hidden; though. http://jsfiddle.net/Lukedturnbull/kvaxmhth/1/

Comment: @LukeTurnbull `visibility` doesn't work in Firefox v32. What browser is working?

Comment: When I used FF32, didn't work.
Now With with GC 37 works.

It's not a good choice use visibility, because that.